# Mount the directory / HOME directory located on a remote Windows 2008 R2

Tags: 12.04, windows, samba, pam

I am currently working on the integration of Ubuntu 12.04 LTS Linux on an Active Directory domain in Windows 2008 R2.
I have managed to integrate my Ubuntu 12.04 machine to AD 2008, my user successfully authenticates to the AD logon.
Software used: Samba - Winbind - Kerberos - NTP

For mounting partitions, I installed: libpam-mount

Everything works when I mount the share eg / media
My config file: / etc / security / pam_mount.conf.xml

```
<volume fstype="cifs" server="share_server" path="%(USER)$" mountpoint="/media/%(USER)" user="*" />
```

I can create and delete files without problems.

my problem
I currently blocks on mounting / HOME for users (like roaming profile)
My config file: / etc / security / pam_mount.conf.xml

```
<volume fstype="cifs" server="share_server" path="%(USER)$" mountpoint="/home/%(USER)" user="*" options="rw,auto,iocharset=utf8" />
```

I configured the / etc / pam.d / common-session

```
session required pam_mkhomedir.so
```

it automatically create the tree if it is missing, locally it does well, but not with the network mount (well it does not because there's some good directories and files created anyway)

When I open the session, I find myself on the empty desktop, no menu, no application launcher.
I have some files that can be found in the user directory on server 2008: Desktop, Documents, Videos, ...

I do not see where the problem is.

Thank you in advance if anyone can give me a little help.

---

cordially
Laurent

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like to me you are authenticating and mounting the remote directory successfully. Your file manager, your window manager, or both may be having trouble with missing files or incorrect permissions.

Suggestions:

Determine what file and window managers you are using and look for errors in logs. Sorry I don't know which logs, or what you might be looking for.

or-

Backup your files on the server and rename your home folder. If there is no home dir, depending on your settings, one may be created for you. This might help.